# Pass multiple parameters in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am fairly new with jquery ajax so any help would be much appreciated, I am trying to pass parameters to my controller but an exception is throw that my parameters are null. Here is my jquery code:

```
$("#btnSave1").click(function () {
            var ConfirmPasswordForm = $("#ConfirmPasswordForm").serialize();
            var Myid = $("#testPurpose").val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/Folder/ConfirmPassword",
                data: {viewModel: ConfirmPasswordForm, folderPath: Myid},
                success: function () {
                    window.location.href = "/Folder/GetFolders1"
                }
            })
        });
```

this is my function in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ConfirmPassword(FoldersandFilesViewModel viewModel, string folderPath)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationUser user1 = UserManager.FindById(userId);
        var result = UserManager.CheckPassword(user1, viewModel.Password);
        if (result)
            DeleteFolder(folderPath);
    }
```

Comment: Confirm password form is a form of type FoldersandFilesViewModel and this is Myid variable <input id="testPurpose" type="hidden" />

Comment: its value is set here: $(".myCustomContainer").on("click", ".my-delete", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                $("#ConfirmPasswordModal").modal('show');
                $("#testPurpose").val(button.attr("data-folder-path"));
            });

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a viewmodel

```
public class FormViewModel
{
public FoldersandFilesViewModel ViewModel {get; set;]
public string FolderPath {get; set;}
}
```

action

```
public IActionResult ConfirmPassword(FormViewModel formViewModel)
{
.....
return Ok();
}
```